# Gmail Compose Link with Body - Signature missing?

Tags: gmail

This URL is automatically setting up receiver, subject and message (body):

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=TO_ADDRESS@example.com&cc=CC_ADDRESS@example.com&bcc=BCC_ADDRESS@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY

However, when you set the parameter `&body=XXX` Gmail automatically removes the signature as well.

Is there any way to force the signature to appear right below the body?

Comment: Is there a solution?

Comment: I don't believe there is.

Comment: Questions about **using web applications** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [webapps.se].